# Extracting relevant information from .obj 3d file

Tags: graphics, 3d, file-format, .obj, wavefront

I have generated a .obj file from a scan of a 3d scanner. However, I am not sure how to interpret all this data. I have looked on wikipedia and understood the general structure of the .ibj file. My goal is to extract some information about the colour and I am not sure how to do that. What do the numbers in the vt line represent and how can I use those to come up with a colour? My end objective is to scan a foot and cancel out the floor "portion" of the scan. When scanning the foot, the floor is also part of the scan and I would like to disregard the floor and concentrate on the foot. Here is a small part of the .obj file:
[image: .obj file]

Comment: why image dump when the obj is ASCII ... simple copy paste from notepad would be simpler and better for those who want to try this ...

Answer (score 1):

Look s like **Wavefront obj** ASCII fileformat ... so google a bit and you will find tons of descriptions. In Your example:

- `v x y z` means point coordinate (vertex) `[x,y,z]`
- `vn nx,ny,nz` means normal vector `(nx,ny,nz)` of last point `[x,y,z]`
- `vt tx,ty` means texture coordinate `[tx,ty]`

**Vertexes** are the points of the polygonal mesh. **Normals** are used for lighting computations (shading) so if you do not use it you can skip it. The **color** is stored in some texture image and you will pick it as a pixel at `[tx,ty]` the range is `tx,ty=<-1,+1>` or `<0,+1>` so you need to rescale to image resolution.

So you need to read all this data to some table and then find section with faces (starts with `f`):

- `f v1,v2,v3` means render polygon with 3 vertexes where `v1,v2,v3` are index of vertex from the table. **Beware the indexing starts from 1** so for **C++** style arrays you need to decrement the indexes by 1.

There are a lot of deviations so without an example is hard to elaborate further (your example shows only the start of vertex table).